# How to export a report between two dates in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Am trying to export report .csv file in codeigniter, the records allocated in two tables in DB , the problem is when i tried to fetch data between two dates its give me blank file, but it works fine without between query!
another thing i need to display report on UI(view) before exporting it which doesn't work.

> the controller:

```
public function Export_appointments() {
    //check if the user is admin
    $this->session->set_userdata('dest_url', site_url('backend/users'));
             if ( ! $this->has_privileges(PRIV_USERS))
            {
         return;
     }
    $this->load->dbutil();
    $this->load->helper('file');
    $this->load->helper('download');
    $this->load->view('backend/settings');
/* read input data*/
$date1 = date('Y-m-d',  strtotime($this->input->post("from_date"))); //date type
$date2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->input->post("to_date")));
/*working query*/
$this->db->select('first_name, last_name,     book_datetime,start_datetime,end_datetime');
$this->db->from('ea_appointments');
$this->db->join('ea_users', 'ea_users.id = ea_appointments.id');
 $this->db->where('ea_users.id_roles',3); 
/* I tried this ------book_datetime is datetime type---*/ 
          $this->db->where('CAST(book_datetime As Date) >= ',$date1);
          $this->db->where('CAST(book_datetime As Date) <= ',$date2);
          /* also this -------
$this->db->where('CAST(book_datetime as date) BETWEEN "'. date('Y-m-d',  strtotime($date1)). '" and "'. date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date2)).'"');*/ 
        $query = $this->db->get()->result_array();
        $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
        $header = array("First_Name","Last_Name","Booking_Date","Start_Date","End_Date"); 
    fputcsv($fp, $header);
    foreach ($query as $key => $value) {
    fputcsv($fp, $value);
    }

    $data = file_get_contents('php://output');
    $name = 'report.csv';

    // Build the headers to push out the file properly.
    header('Pragma: public');     // required
    header('Expires: 0');         // no cache
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Cache-Control: private',false);
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($name).'"');  // Add the file name
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Connection: close');
    exit();
    force_download($name, $data);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

> The view:

```
<?php $hidden = ($privileges[PRIV_SYSTEM_SETTINGS]['view'] == TRUE) ? '' : 'hidden'; ?>
<div id="export" class="tab-pane <?php echo $hidden; ?>">
<form class="row"  method= "post" action="<?php echo base_url();  ?>backend/Export_appointments">
<fieldset class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 miscellaneous-wrapper">
<legend>Export Appointment Data from:</legend>
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="from_date">
<legend>To:</legend>
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="to_date">
<button type="button" id="data-csv-export" class="btn btn-default" onclick="window.location='<?php echo site_url("backend/Export_appointments");?>'">Download report.CSV</button>
<div class="panel-body">
 <div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
   <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Book Date</th>
    <th>Start Date</th>
    <th>End Date</th>
   </tr>
   <?php
  /* foreach($query as $row)
   {
    echo '
    <tr>
     <td>'.$row["first_name"].'</td>
     <td>'.$row["last_name"].'</td>
     <td>'.$row["book_datetime"].'</td>
     <td>'.$row["start_datetime"].'</td>
     <td>'.$row["end_datetime"].'</td>
     </tr> ';  }*/
     ?>
   </table>
   </div>
     </div>
       </fieldset>
          </form>
            </div>
```

Comment: sorry, this is my first time and i was trying to add the code

Answer (score 0):

You can use your "controller name"/export_appointments instead of base_url() in the form url.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You have used $_post instead of $_POST to reference to values posted in the form. Also, you have an exit() statement after your headers, which would be required for the output to prevent further execution, but it is not conditional, and will always exit so it never gets to the load view function. Suggestion before doing the headers and exit:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    // Code that does things only when the form has been submitted. Headers and export features go here.
} else {
    // Do things when the form is NOT submitted. The load view will go here.
}
```

This should get you closer to the solution.

If your dates are already captured in Y-m-d format in your form/form plugin, you can skip the `strtotime()` calls on the dates - in that case, simply put the posted date values in the query. Please also sanitize your inputs before doing so - you're risking SQL injection as it stands.

Comment: still not working for me I have this error: Undefined array key "from_date"

Comment: Your $_POST array seems to not contain the from_date then. Perhaps edit the question and update with your code as it stands now.

Comment: I edit my question, all error message gone but it's still blank